# Not Understanding Where Statement

Tags: sql, where-clause

I am new to SQL, I'm looking through some code for a small database for a medical office. What does the following mean and what will it do...Patient I get, its a field in the DB. This code is repeated for each of the fields.

```
WHERE ( LOWER ( "Patient" ) LIKE ( '%' || LOWER ( :Patient ) || '%' )
```

Answer (score 7):

It does a case insensitive comparison looking for rows where the `"Patient"` column contains the substring passed in the `:Patient` parameter.

`LOWER` converts both sides to lower case.

`||` is the ANSI SQL string concatenation operator.

`%` in a `LIKE` pattern is a wildcard meaning "match any set of zero or more characters".

So if `:Patient` was `Smith` the expression works out as

```
WHERE LOWER ( "Patient" ) LIKE '%smith%'
```